# Change placeholder text color in Magento 2.1.2 search box

Tags: magento-2.1, css, placeholder

How to change the css of a placeholder? I want to change the color of the text "Search entire store here..."

Can you please help me with this?

[image: example]

Comment: Here is similar question with a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: thnku @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Answer (score 2):

In the Magento 2 less documentation there is a file named *css/docs/variables.html* which specifies the placeholder variables:

**Placeholder**

```
@form-element-input-placeholder__color: #c2c2c2; //Form control placeholder color
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #909;
}
```

You will have to enter one for each browser. Looks like you are using the porto theme so the following code will work just place it in your custom css box in theme settings panel. Change the color to whatever you prefer.

```
#search::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #909;
}
#search:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
#search::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
#search:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #909;
}
```